# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type') Error using useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning react and trying to show alert msg on the change of dark to light and light to dark mode. I have tried this code and I'm not able to solve this error. I have given toggle button for dark mode and light mode that is working fine but when I'm using null in useState(null) I'm getting error on alert.js page on line 7

```
Alert.js:7 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type')
    at Alert (Alert.js:7:1)
```

This is my App.Js page

`

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import About from './components/About';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import TextForm from './components/TextForm';
import Alert from './components/Alert';

function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('light'); //to set initial mode to light
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

  const showAlert = (message, type) => {
    setAlert({
      message: message,
      type: type,
    })
  }

  const toggleMode = () => {
    if (mode === 'dark') {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
      showAlert("Dark mode has been enabled", "success");
      setMode('light');
    } else {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#06213d';
      showAlert("Light mode has been enabled", "success");
      setMode('dark')
    }

  }
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar title="Text Utils" mode={mode} toggleMode={toggleMode} />
      <Alert alert={alert} />
      <div className='container my-3'>
        <TextForm heading='Enter the text to analyze below' mode={mode} />
        <About mode={mode}></About>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`
This is my Alert.js Page

`

```
import React from 'react'

function Alert(props) {
    return (
        <div>
             <div className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
             props.alert && <strong>{props.alert.type}</strong>: {props.alert.msg}
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Alert
```

`

I tried solutions from google but dose not work. Is there any way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Initially `alert` state is `null`, so it can't read `props.alert.type`. You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) when reading or you can initialize the state with null values.

`props.alert?.type`

or

```
const [alert, setAlert] = useState({
  message: null,
  type: null,
});
```

Comment: Thank You - I have tried both codes but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You pass object alert in your Alert, component, this component include field type and message. You are using props.alert.msg, but object alert don`t have field msg.

Try  props.alert.message.

And in App component when you define state alert,  initial state better set as object

```js
const [alert, setAlert] = useState({message: null, type: null}).
```

Answer (score 0):

export default function Alert(props) {
return (
<>
{  props.alert && <div className={`alert alert-${props.alert.type} alert-dismissible fade show`} role="alert">
**{props.alert.type}**   {props.alert.message}


}
</>
)
}

hi !
Soo After two days seeing the Error of my console find the actual cause of error . basically  you put whole alert code on curly-braces and use props like this { props.alert && here is your alert code  } its means that  if your props.alert is wrong(null) than your return here is your alert code  this code is not executed oterwise your code is execute successfully . I hope its solve your problem .that's All
thank you ,friends!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).